# Other pages are is not responsive for the same media query

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, fullpage.js

Im using fullpage.js for single page webisite the first that is home page is fit in the viewport but other pages bottom is invisible for the same media query

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: This is an incomplete question.

Answer (score 0):

Fullpage.js is responsive. What do you need to do in media queries?

In documentation you'll find parameters and also some callback functions if you want to perform any operations on sections

```
        //events
        onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){},
        afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){},
        afterRender: function(){},
        afterResize: function(){},
        afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){},
        onSlideLeave: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction, nextSlideIndex){}
```

Comment: So no need of media query can you give me example using these event

Comment: Please refer this code-:
for responsive height and width-:

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/examples/responsiveHeight.html

Comment: there is no html code in your question. i can't generalize the code for you. Use documentation and example files for responsive layout.